# How to do platform specific in aurelia?

Tags: cordova, aurelia

Actually, I am  new to Aurelia, I am  trying to build a mobile application with the help of Cordova, I want different content for different platforms, I am using ECMAScript for Aurelia,
I tried following way but it's not working

```js
      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.platformId === 'browser') {
   console.log("something")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

With a properly configured project, you'll have differently configured build scripts for different platforms. Then you can simply have the build scripts set these variables somewhere for you.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/arjendeblok/aurelia-cordova-skeleton/blob/master/src/main.ts) of how that works:

```
declare const IS_DEV_BUILD: boolean; // The value is supplied by Webpack during the build
declare const IS_CORDOVA: boolean; // The value is supplied by Webpack during the build
export async function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    if (IS_CORDOVA) {
        const cordova = new CordovaEvents();
        await cordova.waitForDeviceReady();
    }
```

These kinds of variables can be set with the webpack DefinePlugin:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ IS_DEV_BUILD: JSON.stringify(isDevBuild), IS_CORDOVA: JSON.stringify(isCordova) }),
```

And you'd pass the env parameters to the cli from the build script, ideally defined in package.json (or package-scripts.js if you're using nps):

```
"build": "webpack --mode development --env.cordova",
```

The concepts are similar if you're working with `aurelia-cli`, but I don't know of any sample project for cordova using aurelia-cli unfortunately.